# Can I make an endless loop of python programs?

Tags: python-3.x

I was wondering how to make program1 run program2 and program2 run program1 and so on. I have already tried using `os.system()` on each program to run the other, but a really long line of errors comes up and says maximum recursion depth reached

Thanks

Comment: Apart from a rather bizarre variation of a fork-bomb - why would you want this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's to prank one of my friends, but i know how to stop it, so I'll tell them after a few minutes. (Don't worry they have lots of RAM)

Comment: Not sure if SO is for helping in those tricks....

Comment: I'm sure I could use it for something else productive as well, such as an easy way do delete files from multiple directories you dont need anymore

Comment: Might I suggest if it's a linux-based system that you use a fork bomb instead? Much more fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except the weirdness of the question :)

What you did is a correct way, but each time you call a new program your stack gets bigger and after a while your stack is full and you get a stack overflow (no you don't get this site :p ), but just an error which this site is named after as you encountered.
If you really want to keep their system busy I would try to do something heavy inside one program.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, or I'll just put a limit on how many times it can duplicate :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make endless call using subprocess module in python.

Below is the example

File: a.py

```
 import subprocess

 print("Program A")
 subprocess.call('python b.py',shell=True)
```

File: b.py

```
import subprocess

print("program B")
subprocess.call('python a.py',shell=True)
```

Run any of the file

```
Output:
program B
Program A
program B
Program A
program B
Program A
program B
Program A
program B
```